# ffmpeg (avcodeclib) & png support

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, png

I'm building ffmpeg libraries on Windows with a `--enable-decoder=png` switch. However, after successful build, there is no png support. Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: We need more details on this question. Which type of png lib you are linking ? What are the other command line arguments you are passing. Also let us know your environment variables (can be obtained by command set)

Comment: What do you mean by "which type of png lib"? Here is the command line used for building: --extra-cflags='-mno-cygwin -mms-bitfields' --extra-ldflags=-Wl,--add-stdcall-alias --target-os=mingw32 --enable- static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --enable-memalign-hack --enable-decoder=mpeg4 --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=png --disable-debug --enable-w32threads --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffplay

Comment: libpng.lib (static) or dll (the dynamic one). Also, did you check ffpmpeg's command line output if it is emitting message related to png while processing pngs.

Comment: There is no libpng.lib, or libpng.dll on my system. Do I have to get the libpng project from somewhere and build it first?

Comment: Have you tried `--enable-encoder=png`? Interestingly in my cygwin environment png is listed as encoder as result of the `configure` command bot not as decoder. libpng is not present, zlib is.

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was Zlib, FFmpeg will only include PNG support if Zlib is found

```
wget zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.xz
tar xf zlib-1.2.8.tar.xz
cd zlib-1.2.8
make -f win32/Makefile.gcc install \
  PREFIX=$HOST- \
  DESTDIR=$PREFIX \
  BINARY_PATH=/bin \
  INCLUDE_PATH=/include \
  LIBRARY_PATH=/lib
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/install-ffmpeg.sh)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Cygwin. Most probably you do not have libpng installed in your Cygwin installation. To install, you need to launch the "setup.exe", which is what you have used to install your Cygwin environment, and find "png" under the installation package. Update and you are ready to use png with your ffmpeg program.